# Change control name in toolbox, without changing the class name

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

I have a control called MyControl with [ToolboxItem(true)] attribute

```
[ToolboxItem(true)]
public class MyControl: Control
{ }
```

and this class appears in the toolbox with name MyControl (as expected):
[image]

Is it possible to change the name of the control **ONLY** in the toolbox, without actually changing the class name e.g. in the toolbox I want to appear "tomato / potato".

Comment: There is a Rename Item option when you right click your custom control in the toolbox, but it does not persist between closing and reopening VS.  Nor does it affect the object once dragged onto your form (i.e. your object is still `MyControl myControl1`).  Which leads me to wonder why the Rename Item option even exists.  I'm still looking for a real answer though.

Comment: I am aware of the rename option, but this is not what I am looking for.